# Class magic/dunder method (mul, rmul)?

Tags: python

I would like to add `__mul__` and `__rmul__` class method to a class to be able to do the following syntax:

```
object - 3 * ObjectType
```

but when I try to do the following:

```
>>> class ClassMult:
...   @classmethod
...   def __mul__(cls, other):
...     print(cls.__qualname__)
...   
...   @classmethod
...   def __rmul__(cls, other):
...     print(cls.__qualname__)
... 
>>> 2 * ClassMult
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'type'
```

Can I achieve the desired result?
If so how can I do it?

Comment: you need to apply * to an *instance* of `ClassMult`. Here you're trying to multiply by the *class*, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This has nothing to do with operator overloading and everything to do with having the class where there should be an instance instead. The code doesn't work for the same reason that `3 * int` doesn't work.

Comment: @RobinZigmond That seems to be why they made it a `@classmethod`.

Comment: You should do something like `2*ClassMult()`

Comment: You could do it with a `metaclass`, not that you should.

Comment: If you really want to be able to multiply the class itself (`ctypes` uses that to good effect), you would need a custom metaclass to implement the relevant dunder methods.

Comment: Yep, I want to do it on the class itself :)
I want to do it for readability sake - we have complex temporal types and we want to be able to say "go x previous" or "go y after". Alternatives syntaxes considered were `period.next(count=2)`, `period - AbstractPeriod.delta(count=2)`, and simply `period - 1`.

I can update the question if someone wants the extra info.

Comment: So the plan is to define a ctypes-like dynamic class creation?

Comment: @PhilippeHebert: I strongly recommend not using metaclasses for that. It doesn't sound like any of the objects involved in those operations really need to be a class. `period - 2 * SomeType` could instead be `period - 2 * some_ordinary_object`, or `period - SomeType(2)`.

Comment: I guess with the common outcry at this idea maybe I shouldn't use a metaclass for this :D . I'll opt for `period - SomeType.delta(2)`. Not as syntactically nice, but I guess I'm saving my ass in the long run :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@classmethod` doesn't work for that. If you want to implement `*` for an object, you have to do so on its class. When the object is itself a class, you need to customize your class's class, a.k.a. its metaclass:

```
class ClassMultMeta(type):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        ...
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        ...

class ClassMult(metaclass=ClassMultMeta):
    pass
```

Note that metaclasses are a highly specialized tool with a lot of subtle caveats, particularly in how they interact with other metaclasses and other language features like `__init_subclass__`. If you don't absolutely need to use a metaclass, it's usually better to not use a metaclass.

Comment: can you also explain the `TypeError` that the OP ran into? i.e. why is the class's type `type`

Comment: @Cresht user defined classes are instances of `type`.

Comment: as in they inherit from `type`, are constructed like objects, or both?

Comment: Classes are objects. Just like `type(3) == int`, `type(int) == type`.

Comment: @Axe319 **all** classes are instances of `type`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True. Even `type` itself is an instance of `type`.

Comment: @Cresht all a `metaclass` is, is a way of saying this is the `class` that my `class` will be an instance of. Since normally, this is `type`s job, if our `metaclass` inherits from `type`, it will still be able to properly create an instance that behaves like a normal `class`, but with additional functionality. Since `__mul__` and friends operate on the instance, if we add them to what our `class` is an instance of, we can use them on the `class` itself.

Comment: @Cresht everything in Python is an object. Including `int`, `str`, `list` are all objects, just like functions, and even classes. The usual class of a class (metaclass) is `type`, but you can create your own class to use as the class of a class, i.e. a metaclass, and generally you want to inherit from `type`