# How do I define a classmethod dunder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class `percent` that I'd like to be able to define `__rsub__` for the class and not instances. For instance using this class:

```
class percent:

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def __rsub__(cls, value: int) -> None:
        return percent(value)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{value}%"
```

This obviously doesn't work, but ultimately I'd like to be able to create a `percent` instance like so:

```
>>> 50-percent
50%
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/70963308/3001761?

Comment: I have now, didn't see that in my searching. Thank you!